# Rails non hash conditions lost table reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, conditional-statements

When using array or string conditions inside Rails query, for example:

Scope in Location model:

```
scope :name_like, ->(keyword) {where("name ilike ?", keyword)}
```

It will have problem when using it with join table who also has column `name`. It is like:

```
Location.joins(:users).name_like('main')
```

It will report ambiguous column name conflicts at `name`.

How should I address this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `name_like` scope to use explicit `name` of `locations`. I suggest to change it as below:

```
scope :name_like, -> (keyword) { where("locations.name ilike ?", keyword) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this

```
scope :by_name, -> { joins(:users).where("users.name like '%?%'",'FirstName' ) }
```

Refer this link below.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope